# Find 30-minute interval values that belong to the 6-hour intervals

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using Binance.Net NuGet package to download historical candle data from Binance. I have a check whether the candle on each 6-hour interval is green and if it is, it enumerates each 30-minute interval inside the 6-hour interval.

A working example is given in the code below. The snippet basically works but the problem is instead of downloading the candles from Binance's REST once again with `GetKlines`, it should use the `_30m` array instead, because it would be too slow to download the data using GetKlines everytime we enumerate them each 6-hour interval candle, that's why I'm pulling the data in the beginning at once and then I can store it, re-use it, etc.

Briefly, I need to find the 30-minute interval candles that belong to the 6-hour intervals.

```cs
using Binance.Net;
using Binance.Net.Enums;
using Binance.Net.Interfaces;
using Binance.Net.Objects.Spot;
using Binance.Net.Objects.Spot.MarketData;
using CryptoExchange.Net.Authentication;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace BacktestingTest
{
    public class JsonEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
    {
        public bool Equals(T x, T y)
        {
            return string.Equals
            (
                JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x),
                JsonConvert.SerializeObject(y)
            );
        }

        public int GetHashCode(T obj)
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj).GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    public static partial class LinqExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> ExceptUsingJsonCompare<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second)
            => first.Except(second, new JsonEqualityComparer<T>());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This class is the most important.
    /// </summary>
    public class Backtesting
    {
        private readonly IBinanceClient _client;

        public Backtesting()
        {
            _client = new BinanceClient(new BinanceClientOptions()
            {
                ApiCredentials = new ApiCredentials("xxx", "yyy"),
                AutoTimestamp = true,
                AutoTimestampRecalculationInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)
            });
        }

        private readonly DateTime StartDate = new DateTime(2020, 1, 1);
        private readonly DateTime EndDate = new DateTime(2020, 10, 2);

        private List<BinanceSpotKline> GetCandlesByStartDateEndDate(string symbol, KlineInterval interval, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
        {
            if (endDate.Date > DateTime.UtcNow.Date)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("The end date is greater than today.");

            var candles = _client.Spot.Market.GetKlines(symbol, interval, startTime: startDate, endTime: endDate, limit: 200).Data.ToList();

            while (endDate > candles.Last().OpenTime)
            {
                var moreCandles = _client.Spot.Market.GetKlines(symbol, interval, startTime: candles.Last().OpenTime, endTime: endDate, limit: 1000).Data.ToList();
                candles.AddRange(moreCandles.ExceptUsingJsonCompare(candles));
            }

            return candles.Cast<BinanceSpotKline>().ToList();
        }

        private bool IsCandleGreen(IBinanceKline candle)
        {
            return candle.Open < candle.Close;
        }

        public void Perform()
        {
            var _30m = GetCandlesByStartDateEndDate("TRXUSDT", KlineInterval.ThirtyMinutes, StartDate, EndDate);
            var _6h = GetCandlesByStartDateEndDate("TRXUSDT", KlineInterval.SixHour, StartDate, EndDate);
            
            // Dates match - works fine
            var _30m_first = _30m.First();
            var _30m_last = _30m.Last();

            var _6h_first = _6h.First();
            var _6h_last = _6h.Last();

            // Enumerate 6h candles and 
            foreach (var candle in _6h)
            {
                if (IsCandleGreen(candle))
                {
                    // Which candles from 30m interval belong to that 6h interval. An example is given below:

                    // 1) FIRST ITERATION - OpenTime = {1/1/2020 12:00:00 AM}

                    // 30m interval candles lying in the 6h interval
                    // OpenTime = {1/1/2020 12:00:00 AM}
                    // OpenTime = {1/1/2020 12:30:00 AM}
                    // OpenTime = {1/1/2020 1:00:00 AM}
                    // OpenTime = {1/1/2020 1:30:00 AM}
                    // OpenTime = {1/1/2020 2:00:00 AM}
                    // OpenTime = {1/1/2020 2:30:00 AM}
                    // OpenTime = {1/1/2020 3:00:00 AM}
                    // OpenTime = {1/1/2020 3:30:00 AM}
                    // OpenTime = {1/1/2020 4:00:00 AM}
                    // OpenTime = {1/1/2020 4:30:00 AM}
                    // OpenTime = {1/1/2020 5:00:00 AM}
                    // OpenTime = {1/1/2020 5:30:00 AM}

                    // 2) SECOND ITERATION - OpenTime = {1/1/2020 6:00:00 AM}

                    // 30m interval candles lying in the 6h interval
                    // OpenTime = {1/1/2020 6:00:00 AM}
                    // OpenTime = {1/1/2020 6:30:00 AM}
                    // OpenTime = {1/1/2020 7:00:00 AM}
                    // OpenTime = {1/1/2020 7:30:00 AM}
                    // OpenTime = {1/1/2020 8:00:00 AM}
                    // OpenTime = {1/1/2020 8:30:00 AM}
                    // OpenTime = {1/1/2020 9:00:00 AM}
                    // OpenTime = {1/1/2020 9:30:00 AM}
                    // OpenTime = {1/1/2020 10:00:00 AM}
                    // OpenTime = {1/1/2020 10:30:00 AM}
                    // OpenTime = {1/1/2020 11:00:00 AM}
                    // OpenTime = {1/1/2020 11:30:00 AM}

                    var candles = _client.Spot.Market.GetKlines("TRXUSDT", KlineInterval.ThirtyMinutes, startTime: candle.OpenTime, endTime: candle.OpenTime.AddHours(6), limit: 1000).Data.SkipLast(1).ToList(); // TODO: This has to get values from _30m array and not directly from Binance once again.
                
                    foreach (var innerCandle in candles)
                    {
                        // There will be checks for those 30-minute interval candles
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Backtesting backtesting = new Backtesting();
            backtesting.Perform();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
            const long TICKS_PER_SECOND = 10000000;  //tick = 100ns
            long SIX_HOUR = 6 * 3600 * TICKS_PER_SECOND;

            List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>() {
                DateTime.Parse("1/1/2020 12:00:00 AM"),
                DateTime.Parse("1/1/2020 12:30:00 AM"),
                DateTime.Parse("1/1/2020 1:00:00 AM"),
                DateTime.Parse("1/1/2020 1:30:00 AM"),
                DateTime.Parse("1/1/2020 2:00:00 AM"),
                DateTime.Parse("1/1/2020 2:30:00 AM"),
                DateTime.Parse("1/1/2020 3:00:00 AM"),
                DateTime.Parse("1/1/2020 3:30:00 AM"),
                DateTime.Parse("1/1/2020 4:00:00 AM"),
                DateTime.Parse("1/1/2020 4:30:00 AM"),
                DateTime.Parse("1/1/2020 5:00:00 AM"),
                DateTime.Parse("1/1/2020 5:30:00 AM"),
                DateTime.Parse("1/1/2020 6:00:00 AM"),
                DateTime.Parse("1/1/2020 6:30:00 AM"),
                DateTime.Parse("1/1/2020 7:00:00 AM"),
                DateTime.Parse("1/1/2020 7:30:00 AM"),
                DateTime.Parse("1/1/2020 8:00:00 AM"),
                DateTime.Parse("1/1/2020 8:30:00 AM"),
                DateTime.Parse("1/1/2020 9:00:00 AM"),
                DateTime.Parse("1/1/2020 9:30:00 AM"),
                DateTime.Parse("1/1/2020 10:00:00 AM"),
                DateTime.Parse("1/1/2020 10:30:00 AM"),
                DateTime.Parse("1/1/2020 11:00:00 AM"),
                DateTime.Parse("1/1/2020 11:30:00 AM"),
            };

            var groups = dates.GroupBy(x => x.Ticks/SIX_HOUR).Select(x => x.ToList()).ToList();
```

Comment: So basically that's what you meant https://pastebin.com/ckqMc7HJ?

Comment: Yes.   The static constants are available in the Timespan class :    public const long TicksPerDay = 864000000000; public const long TicksPerHour = 36000000000;public const long TicksPerMillisecond = 10000;public const long TicksPerMinute = 600000000; public const long TicksPerSecond = 10000000;

Comment: thank you! I replaced your constant with the TimeSpan one: `long sixHour = 6 * 3600 * TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond;`